# How to upload a file with selenium on remote node [Python]

Tags: python, selenium, file-upload, webdriver

Found here (stackoverflow) a way to handle a file selection on local host. I'm using Autoit and run a local script which writes in the file path.
But how can I run this on the **remote** node, when I'm using selenium hub.
Is there a way run on a remote node a command line (windows) process ?
Prefer Python example.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution, basically you need to run AutoIt server on the node:
https://github.com/daluu/AutoItDriverServer

Comment: https://autumnator.wordpress.com/2011/12/22/autoit-sikuli-and-other-tools-with-selenium-grid/